# Dask: ValueError: Integer column has NA values

Tags: dask

I tried to use dask and found something that appears to be a bug in dask.dataframe.read_csv.

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
types = {'id': 'int16', 'Semana': 'uint8', 'Agencia_ID': 'uint16', 'Canal_ID': 'uint8',
         'Ruta_SAK': 'uint16' ,'Cliente_ID': 'float32', 'Producto_ID': 'float32'}
name_map = {'Semana': 'week', 'Agencia_ID': 'agency', 'Canal_ID': 'channel',
            'Ruta_SAK': 'route', 'Cliente_ID': 'client', 'Producto_ID': 'prod'}

test =  dd.read_csv(os.path.join(datadir, 'test.csv'), usecols=types.keys(), dtype=types)
test = test.rename(columns=name_map)
```

gives :

ValueError: Integer column has NA values in column 1

However, the same pandas read_csv operation completes fine and does not yield any NA:

```
types = {'id': 'int16', 'Semana': 'uint8', 'Agencia_ID': 'uint16', 'Canal_ID': 'uint8',
         'Ruta_SAK': 'uint16' ,'Cliente_ID': 'float32', 'Producto_ID': 'float32'}
name_map = {'Semana': 'week', 'Agencia_ID': 'agency', 'Canal_ID': 'channel',
            'Ruta_SAK': 'route', 'Cliente_ID': 'client', 'Producto_ID': 'prod'}

test =  pd.read_csv(os.path.join(datadir, 'test.csv'), usecols=types.keys(), dtype=types)
test = test.rename(columns=name_map)

test.isnull().any()

id         False
week       False
agency     False
channel    False
route      False
client     False
prod       False
dtype: bool
```

Should I consider this to be an established bug and raise a JIRA for it?

Full traceback:

---

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
      4             'Ruta_SAK': 'route', 'Cliente_ID': 'client', 'Producto_ID': 'prod'}
      5 
----> 6 test =  dd.read_csv(os.path.join(datadir, 'test.csv'), usecols=types.keys(), dtype=types)
      7 test = test.rename(columns=name_map)

D:\PROGLANG\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\dask\dataframe\csv.pyc in read_csv(filename, blocksize, chunkbytes, collection, lineterminator, compression, sample, enforce, storage_options, **kwargs)
    195     else:
    196         header = sample.split(b_lineterminator)[0] + b_lineterminator
--> 197     head = pd.read_csv(BytesIO(sample), **kwargs)
    198 
    199     df = read_csv_from_bytes(values, header, head, kwargs,

D:\PROGLANG\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.pyc in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, tupleize_cols, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, skip_footer, doublequote, delim_whitespace, as_recarray, compact_ints, use_unsigned, low_memory, buffer_lines, memory_map, float_precision)
    560                     skip_blank_lines=skip_blank_lines)
    561 
--> 562         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    563 
    564     parser_f.**name** = name

D:\PROGLANG\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.pyc in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    323         return parser
    324 
--> 325     return parser.read()
    326 
    327 _parser_defaults = {

D:\PROGLANG\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.pyc in read(self, nrows)
    813                 raise ValueError('skip_footer not supported for iteration')
    814 
--> 815         ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
    816 
    817         if self.options.get('as_recarray'):

D:\PROGLANG\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.pyc in read(self, nrows)
   1312     def read(self, nrows=None):
   1313         try:
-> 1314             data = self._reader.read(nrows)
   1315         except StopIteration:
   1316             if self._first_chunk:

pandas\parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader.read (pandas\parser.c:8748)()

pandas\parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_low_memory (pandas\parser.c:9003)()

pandas\parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_rows (pandas\parser.c:10022)()

pandas\parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader._convert_column_data (pandas\parser.c:11397)()

pandas\parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader._convert_tokens (pandas\parser.c:12093)()

pandas\parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader._convert_with_dtype (pandas\parser.c:13057)()

ValueError: Integer column has NA values in column 1

Comment: I can't tell if this is a bug without being able to easily reproduce it.  Can you raise a github issue with a reproducible example?

Comment: sure. Will do. Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/1480